# AsyncTask returns won't pass to other methods

Tags: android, android-asynctask, parameter-passing

I've looked into many issues and example with this regard but failed to understand and solve the problem. The problem is that I need to get the String array from my InBackground method in my AsyncTask class to another class where some processes occur to the data.

Here is my myMapService class:

```
public class myMapService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private keyword activity;

    private String rst = " " ; 

    private String[] strArr1;
    private String[] strArr2;
    private String[] resultList;

    public String[] getResultList() { return this.resultList; }


    public myMapService(keyword activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... arg0) {


        String result = "";
        int responseCode = 0;

        int executeCount = 0;
        HttpResponse response;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try 
        {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://XXX.com/ccvo/mel-asset-data/query.php?lon="+ arg0[0].toString() + "&lat="+ arg0[1].toString() +"&within=" + arg0[2].toString()  + "&keyword="+ arg0[3].toString().replace(" ", "%20"));


            Log.v("Results", "from web: " + arg0[0]);
            Log.v("Results", "from web: " + arg0[1]);
            Log.v("Results", "from web: " + arg0[2]);
            Log.v("Results", "from web: " + arg0[3]);


                do
                {
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Passing paratmeters.. ("+(executeCount+1)+"/5)");
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    executeCount++;
                    response = client.execute(httppost);
                    responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();                        

                } while (executeCount < 5 && responseCode == 408);

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    result = line.trim();
                    sb.append(line);

                }
        }catch (Exception e2) {
            responseCode = 408;
            e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        rst = result.toString();


// splits everything        
        if(rst != null && rst.length() > 0)
        {
          strArr1 = rst.split("\\|");
          for(int i=0;i<strArr1.length;i++)
          {


                Log.d("Results", "Array size1.1 "  + i);

            Log.v("Results", "Array split1.2 "  + strArr1[i] );


            if(strArr1[i] != null && strArr1[i].length() >0 && strArr1[i].contains(","))
            {

           strArr2 = strArr1[i].split(",");
              for(int j=0; j<strArr2.length ;j++)
              {
                 // strArr3[i][j] = strArr2[j].toString();

                  if(strArr2.length == 4)
                  {

                    // int temp =  Integer.parseInt(strArr2[j]) ;
                    //  strArr2[j] = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(strArr2[j])) ;
                  }
                    Log.d("Results", "Array size2.3 "  + j );

                Log.d("Results", "Array split2.4 "  + strArr2[j] );


              }
            }
          }
        }



/*      if(rst != null && rst.length() > 0)
        {
          strArr = rst.split("\\|");

          for(int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++)
          {
            Log.d("Results", "Array split 1: " + strArr[i]);
           // Log.d("Results", "Array split 2: " + arrfetch[i]);

          }
        }
        */
        this.resultList = strArr2; 

        return strArr2;
    }



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] strArr2)
{
    progressDialog.dismiss();

}

}
```

The strArr2 array returns ategory,latitude,longitude,distance values. This class is fired through a button listener whereas the map will come up with available objects. In my keyword.java :

```
View firstButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    gps = new GPSTracker(keyword.this);



    // check if GPS enabled


        String latitude = Double.toString(gps.getLatitude());
        String longitude = Double.toString(gps.getLongitude());

        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(keyword.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        myMapService myMapService = new myMapService(keyword.this, progressDialog);
        myMapService.execute(longitude.toString(),latitude.toString(), withinn.toString(), keywordSeleced.toString() );


        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), GoogleMapsAppActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(i);


        }
        });
```

I need to use the results of my AsyncTask class in my GoogleMapsAppActivity.java where it extends MapActivity. I need pass those values to these lines:

```
 Drawable makerDefault = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.poke);
 MirItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MirItemizedOverlay(makerDefault);
 itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem((int) (1E6 * -37.720754), (int) (1E6 * 145.048798), "La trobe");
 mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
 MapController mc = mapView.getController();
 mc.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int) (1E6 * -37.720754), (int) (1E6 * 145.048798))); /
 mc.zoomToSpan(itemizedOverlay.getLatSpanE6(), itemizedOverlay.getLonSpanE6());
```

any help is really really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should try pass the value in `onPostExecute` method. According to your code, you didn't do anything but stop the spinner in post execute.

Comment: I tried this before but it gives me an error in **getResources()**

Answer (score 1):

Have `onPostExecute()` call a method on your `GoogleMapsAppActivity` that contains those lines.

Comment: I tried this but it seems that **onPostExecute()** cannot see all methods.

It gives me an error in **Drawable makerDefault = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.poke);**. To be specific, in **getResources()**.

Comment: @user1715137: I did not write "paste the lines of code you have above into `onPostExecute()`. I wrote "have `onPostExecute()` **call a method on your `GoogleMapsAppActivity`** that contains those lines." (emphasis added)

Answer (score 0):

in your onPostExecute() method :

```
super.onPostExecute(strArr2);
```

It will return strArr2 to your calling class

in your calling activity after the myMapService.execute() :

```
String[] results = myMapService.get();
//results == strArr2
```

just simple as that !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this but the app crashes at this line!

Comment: give us the logcat. It's weird because that's what I use and it works just fine.

Comment: : E/AndroidRuntime(2752): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
: E/AndroidRuntime(2752): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.phooogle/com.example.phooogle.GoogleMapsAppActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
: E/AndroidRuntime(2752):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
com.example.phooogle.GoogleMapsAppActivity.onCreate(GoogleMapsAppActivity.java:68)

Comment: What's line 68 in your activity ? Be more precise it's really difficult to help you without info